# Plunger doesn’t stop all water

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, bathtub

I put in a pvc linkage and plunger and it’s not stopping the water from draining slowly from tub. I tried all positions on it and same result. I bought a brass setup and cannot get plunger down far enough to put plate back on. At a loss for ideas right now.

Comment: It really might help if you posted some photos of what you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

I'm willing to bet that it is dirt and grime in the plumbing that is preventing a good seal. I would take out the linkage and plunger and clean out the pipe at least to the length of the plunger unit. There are several ways to do this but it should be mechanical in nature, like scrubbing a dirty pan. Here is one example of a tool that you can buy and you can make one yourself with some stiff wire and a rag. DO NOT lose the rag in the pipe!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I’ll give it a shot.